# Picking image from picture folder - "The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk."

Tags: c#, image, mobile, camera, uwp

I am making an UWP app in C# where the user can choose to take a picture or use an exisiting one. The image picker is opened with this code

```
            FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation =    PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

On a physical device I get this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070019)
```

The weird thing is that I don't get an exception on any of the emulators and it used to work on the physical device too. Any suggestions or explanations?

Comment: Try manually uninstall the app from the device and deploy it again. See what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately that changed nothing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Likely a hardware issue based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms837466.aspx . But someone has solved this issue by factory resetting the phone. And I think you can change the SD card if you have.

Comment: I will try factory resetting it since it's a brand new device, but you never know. If that doesn't work I'll try with a new SD card, but thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your Properties\WMAppManifest.xml file. Make sure that the matadata there is correct. For example, check if the Type attribute is correct ("badabumm.ScheduledAgent" in the example below).

```
<Tasks>      
    <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="badabumm.xaml" />
    <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
            <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="badabumm Agent" Source="badabumm Agent" Type="badabumm.ScheduledAgent" />
    </ExtendedTask>
</Tasks>
```

This solution was originally proposed in this [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/a973955e-0981-4be8-8ac0-8dfcb9dc2917/periodictask?forum=wpdevelop).